# types (integer, Boolean,..) in JSON by using JSON_encode

Tags: php, json

I have an array similar to :

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => John                    
                [id] => 1
                [pass] => 0
            )
```

The array is returned by a sql query. Now I need to use `json_encode` and I want the id to be integer and pass Boolean, but they get string types after `json_encode`. How can I do it with the correct datatypes in `json_encode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the array, casting each value with the key of `pass` to a boolean and each `id` to an integer like so:

```
<?php

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $result->id = (int) $result->id;
    $result->pass = (bool) $result->pass;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this still results in json_encode returning an int instead of a bool.

Answer (score 2):

For the type conversions, you can iterate over the list first and cast the relevant properties:

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $d->id = (int)$d->id;
    $d->pass = (bool)$d->pass;
}
```

For the string conversion issue; the 2nd argument of [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) is `options` (a bitmask). The available options are listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). The relevant option in your case is `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, which will prevent your numbers from being converted to strings in the resulting JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Except columns will be strings when fetched from a result, even if the column type is int or double, boolean, etc.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I just checked and you're right, how have I never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is integer. to make `pass` boolean set it as `boolean` (using `true`, `false`) or cast it to boolean:

```
$obj->pass = (bool)$obj->pass;
```